# server side independent application

Tags: php, ajax, web, server, client

EDIT:

the server application is a pricer, with

- a main calculatePrice function that needs to execute various timeconsuming tasks (get market data from external sources, do some calculations, etc)
- when the application starts it will indefinitely run the pricing function (calculatePrice inside an infinite while loop with maybe a 10sec wait between each iteration so the next one will request updated market data from external sources)
- each calculation result should be persisted (timestamp, stock, price), in a cache or db or published to a data bus (whatever the method it will be stored somewhere)

--> so this application has been started and is running on its own indefinetely calculating stock prices and persisting them

now comes along my html client with a simple get stock price button.

-the get stock function will send an ajax request to a server php script requestPrice.php
then the requestPrice php script would ask the infamous application for it's latest calculation
finally the requestPrice php ajax returns a json array with stamp and price, and in the client html you could have a div that displays "latest price XX.YY calculated at HH:MM

so for me the idea is to create this independant continuously running pricing application.

found a lot of close answers but nothing corresponding exactly to what i'm looking for, all of them are calling server side scripts instead of having an independent application running on its own

Comment: Why not just use `DateTime` and pass in the relevant `DateTimeZone` object as/when you need to? No need for a separate application for that.

Comment: thanks but the timezone example is just an example, my second application won't be doing that but i need it to be continually doing operations so that when i call it i get the latest result rather than triggering the start of the operation which would take quite some time

Comment: ok - well, yes it's feasible but with the amount of information we've got to go on I couldn't say whether it was a good idea or not... depends an lot on what you're actually trying to do. I suspect this should probably be closed as *"too broad"* to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem, but I'm not completely sure about it..
Anyway, I think you might need to setup an entry in the system crontab that executes your script automatically at predefined intervals.

Then you can perform your "polling" to the server or whatever call you need to your files.

If you need some more reactive "real-time" technology you could rely on websockets, tho. There's a cool library for php called [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)

Comment: thanks I checked the Ratchet library but from what I see it seems more of a communication (websocket) protocol rather than an application type or desgin, am I wrong ?